# How to prove the 2-norm of an invertible matrix is exactly the reciprocal of its minimum singular value?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix

If a matrix $A_{n\times n}$ is invertible, then

$\left\|A^{-1}\right\|_2 = \dfrac{1}{\min\limits_{i} \sigma_i}$

where $\sigma_i$ is the $i$-th singular value of $A$

Comment: If this is a homework question (and it looks like something that appears verbatim in every linear algebra textbook ever written), you _must_ tag it as such and show that you have put in reasonable effort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Singular value decomposition of $A$ can be written as $A=USV^T$ with $S$ being a diagonal matrix of singular values of $\sigma_i$.

Euclidean norm of a matrix can be written as : $||A||_2=\sigma_{max}(A)$, meaning that the norm is the maximum singular value.

If $A$ is invertible, then $A^{-1}=(USV^T)^{-1}$.

From here it follows:

$$A^{-1}=(USV^T)^{-1}
      =(V^T)^{-1}S^{-1}U^{-1}
$$

If $A$ is a real valued matrix, then from orthogonality the expression further reduces to:
$$A^{-1}=VS^{-1}U^T.$$

This new matrix $A^{-1}$ now has singular values $S^{-1}$, and its norm would be $\max(\text{diag}(S^{-1}))$, where $\text{diag}$ takes the diagonal of the matrix. Because $S$ is a diagonal matrix, its inverse is computed by simply inverting every single element. Therefore,

$||A^{-1}||_2=\sigma_{max}(A^{-1})=\max\limits_{i} \text{diag}(S^{-1})_i = \max\limits_{i}\frac{1}{\sigma_i}=\frac{1}{\min\limits_{i}{\sigma_i}}$ and this completes the proof.

Comment: Of course, you've started with $\| A \|_{2}=\sigma_{max}(A)$.  It isn't clear whether the original poster is aware of that fact or is willing to assume it.

Comment: Well, considering the structure of the question, I guess this is a fair starting point as it is not explicitly stated. If desired it could also be interpreted either geometrically (http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring12/cos598C/svdchapter.pdf) or algebraically using the induced norm $||A||_2=\max{\frac{||Ax||}{||x||}}$, where $x$ is real and non-zero. This is only a special case of $L_p$ norm. If $||x||_2=1$ is assumed, the maximizer is the largest singular value.

Answer (score 11):

I think I'd rather see it done this way. Since $A$ is invertible, then $\min_i\sigma_i>0$, $$
\min_i\sigma_i = \inf_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2} \quad\Longleftrightarrow
\frac{1}{\min_i\sigma_i} = \sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|x\|_2}{\|Ax\|_2}.
$$
Then we have
$$
\frac{1}{\min_i\sigma_i} 
= \sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|x\|_2}{\|Ax\|_2}
= \sup_{A^{-1}y\neq 0}\frac{\|A^{-1}y\|_2}{\|y\|_2}
= \sup_{y\neq 0}\frac{\|A^{-1}y\|_2}{\|y\|_2}
= \|A^{-1}\|_2.
$$
where we have made the substitution $Ax=y$, and utilized the fact that $A^{-1}y=0\Longleftrightarrow y=0$, again since $A$ is invertible.